# Foreign key is always set to null

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

This is user pojo

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User 
{

//data members
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer userId;
@Column(length = 30)
@NotEmpty(message="UserName connot be null")
private String userName;
@Range(min=6,max=12)
@NotEmpty(message="Password connot be null")
private String password;

@Column(length = 40,unique=true)
@NotEmpty(message="Email connot be null")
@Email(message="Invalid Email")
private String email;
@NotEmpty(message="gender field is must")
@Column(length = 15)
private String gender;
@Column(length = 15)
private String verification;
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private UserAddress useradd;

/*

@NotEmpty(message="phone number cannot be null")
private String phoneNo;
@NotEmpty(message="Address connot be null")
private String address;
private String shippingInfo;
*/


//constructors
public User()
{
    super();
}
public User(String userName, String password, String email, String gender) {
    super();
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.gender = gender;
}




//getter and setter
public String getGender() 
{
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}


public String getVerification() {
    return verification;
}
public void setVerification(String verification) {
    this.verification = verification;
}





public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}


public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}



public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


//toString
public UserAddress getUseradd() {
    return useradd;
}
public void setUseradd(UserAddress useradd) {
    this.useradd = useradd;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [userId=" + userId + ", userName=" + userName + ", 
    password=" + password + ", email=" + email
    + ", gender=" + gender + ", verification=" + verification + "]";
}

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_adr")
public class UserAddress {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(length = 400)
@NotEmpty(message="Address can't be Empty")
private String address;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="userId")
private User user;

@Embedded
private Phone myPhone;

public UserAddress() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



public UserAddress(String address) {
    super();
    this.address = address;

}



public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}



public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Phone getMyPhone() {
    return myPhone;
}

public void setMyPhone(Phone myPhone) {
    this.myPhone = myPhone;
}

}
```

In the database table in foreign key column every time null value is entered for each row. But if i copy paste these pojos in hibernate project they work flawlessly.

Comment: What is set to null, when doing what? Post the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry for posting in wrong manner. Now my problem is solved, it was because i forgot to set bi-directional association.